# python __init__ error on Windows only

Tags: python, windows, init

I am quite new to python...

```
 import sys, os, time, py4chan, urllib from urllib2 import urlopen, URLError, HTTPError

 def refreshthread(boardin,no):
     global thread
     global topic
     board = py4chan.Board(boardin)
     thread = board.getThread(int(no))
     topic = thread.topic
     time.sleep(2.5)

 def dlfile(url, folder):

     try:
         f = urlopen(url)

         with open(folder + "/" + os.path.basename(url), "wb") as local_file:
             local_file.write(f.read())
             print "Downloaded to " + str(folder + "/" + os.path.basename(url)) 

     except HTTPError, e:
         print "HTTP Error:", e.code, url
     except URLError, e:
         print "URL Error:", e.reason, url

 def getsize(uri):
     file = urllib.urlopen(uri)
     size = file.headers.get("content-length")
     file.close()
     return str(int(size) / 1024)

 def main():
     boardtag = str(raw_input("Board: "))
     threadno = int(raw_input("Thread id: "))
     folder = str(raw_input("Save to folder: "))
     print "Getting thread information..."
     refreshthread(boardtag,threadno)
     print "Subject: " + topic.Subject
     while(True):
         if not os.path.exists(folder): os.makedirs(folder)
         refreshthread(boardtag,threadno)
         for imgurl in thread.Files():
             if imgurl is not None and not os.path.exists(folder + "/" + os.path.basename(imgurl)):
                 print "A wild image appears! " + "(" + getsize(imgurl) + "kb)" 
                 dlfile(imgurl,folder)
             else:
                 pass

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

I coded this on linux and it runs perfectly, but if I run this on windows, I get this error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)
```

Which is quite strange as I haven't defined **init**.
Could this be an **init** from another module?

The py4chan module seems to work fine if i code other scripts.
Both machines have same python version too.

**EDIT**(Full error):

```
Getting thread information...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "4chan.py", line 59, in <module>
    main()
  File "4chan.py", line 46, in main
    refreshthread(boardtag,threadno)
  File "4chan.py", line 15, in refreshthread
    board = py4chan.Board(boardin)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)
```

**Edit:**Okay, i had two different modules of the same name. All working now.
I shouldn't be allowed on this website.

Comment: Paste the entire error message, which will include a file and line number.

Comment: You probably have different versions of the py4chan module

Comment: Building off @JBernardo 's comment, it looks like one version of the .Board()` call might not be using default arguments - I'd look at the `__init__` method for `Board`.

Comment: absolutely correct JBernado. I didn't even think to get the module from the same site. Silly me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `py4chan.Board` class needs to be constructed with 3 arguments, not 1.  This line in the `refreshthread` function:

```
board = py4chan.Board(boardin)
```

Should look something this:

```
board = py4chan.Board(base_url, post_url, filesize)
```

Comment: Okay, this makes sense. I had this issue because the py4chan.Board class is different to the 'official' py4chan module. I had actually built the script on a totally different module.

Answer (score 0):

At a first glance, you appear to have hardcoded `/` as a directory separator in two places. In Windows, the directory separator is `\`.

Comment: True, though *most* of Windows also recognizes `/`, and it won't cause this specific error.

Answer (score 0):

The py4chan module I just grabbed from http://py4chan.sourceforge.net/ has this definition for `Board.__init__`:

```
class Board:
    def __init__(self, base_url, post_url, filesize):
```

This expects 4 arguments (including the implicit `self`), so you're missing the `post_url` and `filesize` arguments (whatever those are).